# Access of first sub-array from a multi-dimensional array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, reshape, sub-array

I make confusions between the `shape` function, the `len` function and the first element of a multi-dimensional array `F_matrix[0]`:

Here the output of below code :

```
len(C_matrix) =  1
len(F_matrix) =  1
len(F_matrix).shape =  (1, 8, 8)
len(F_matrix[0]) =  8
    F_matrix[0] =  [[ 4.56867353e+06 -4.99852287e+05 -1.26264284e+06 -5.49992651e+05
  -5.16320280e+04 -1.29914316e+04  5.88986230e+02 -7.90882774e+04]
 [-4.99852287e+05  3.69070386e+06  8.50885784e+04 -9.27921050e+04
  -7.37865334e+05  1.30299311e+05  6.85201453e+04 -9.41043202e+05]
 [-1.26264284e+06  8.50885784e+04  8.53288805e+05  2.63907061e+05
   1.53895305e+04 -6.16652749e+04 -9.04745867e+03 -1.25665562e+04]
 [-5.49992651e+05 -9.27921050e+04  2.63907061e+05  1.29887819e+05
   3.52885203e+04 -1.63641173e+04 -4.59672776e+03  1.35727607e+04]
 [-5.16320281e+04 -7.37865334e+05  1.53895305e+04  3.52885203e+04
   1.74401118e+05 -2.17908075e+04 -1.52244782e+04  2.11406152e+05]
 [-1.29914316e+04  1.30299311e+05 -6.16652749e+04 -1.63641173e+04
  -2.17908075e+04  1.83645151e+04  4.09438482e+03 -1.96038555e+04]
 [ 5.88986230e+02  6.85201453e+04 -9.04745867e+03 -4.59672776e+03
  -1.52244782e+04  4.09438482e+03  1.69590361e+03 -1.74421374e+04]
 [-7.90882774e+04 -9.41043202e+05 -1.25665562e+04  1.35727607e+04
   2.11406152e+05 -1.96038555e+04 -1.74421374e+04  3.25613787e+05]]
```

So, for first element of `F_matrix[0]`, I get a 8x8 = 64 elements

But why I get `len(F_matrix[0]) =  8` ? `F_matrix[0]` should contain 64 elements, shouldn' it ?

```
i,j,l = 1,0,0
while i < tri_len:
    while j < i:
        while s < len(C_matrix):
            Mat_order[s] = 1./np.sqrt(np.linalg.det(np.array([[C_matrix[s][j][j],C_matrix[s][i][j]], [C_matrix[s][j][i],C_matrix[s][i][i]]])))
            s=s+1
        s=0
        SSS = Mat_order.argsort()
        Mat_order = Mat_order[SSS]
        C_matrix = C_matrix[SSS]
        couleur = couleur[SSS]
        ## DEBUG                                                                     
        ##while l < len(F_matrix):                                                   
        print 'len(C_matrix) = ', len(C_matrix)                                      
        print 'len(F_matrix) = ', len(F_matrix)                                      
        print 'len(F_matrix).shape = ', F_matrix.shape                               
        print 'len(F_matrix[0]) = ', len(F_matrix[0])                                
        while l < len(F_matrix):                                                     
        ## END                                                                       
            sq_tab_A = np.array([[C_matrix[l][j][j],C_matrix[l][i][j]], [C_matrix[l][j][i],C_matrix[l][i][i]]])
            sq_tab_B = np.array([[C_matrix[l][j][j],C_matrix[l][i][j]], [C_matrix[l][j][i],C_matrix[l][i][i]]])
            if (i != len(F_matrix[0])-1 and j!=0):                                   
                ellipsePlot_A=plt_ell2(C_matrix[l][j][j],C_matrix[l][i][i],C_matrix[l][i][j],[fid_values[j],fid_values[i]],sq_tab_A,'0.8',couleur[l],2.48,0.8,"","",minx[j],maxx[j],minx[i],maxx[i],tri_len,tri_len,tri_len*i+(j+1),i,j)
            
            elif (i != len(F_matrix[0])-1):                                          
                ellipsePlot_A=plt_ell2(C_matrix[l][j][j],C_matrix[l][i][i],C_matrix[l][i][j],[fid_values[j],fid_values[i]],sq_tab_A,'0.8',couleur[l],2.48,0.8,"",x[i],minx[j],maxx[j],minx[i],maxx[i],tri_len,tri_len,tri_len*i+(j+1),i,j)                             
            
            elif (j != 0):
                ellipsePlot_A=plt_ell2(C_matrix[l][j][j],C_matrix[l][i][i],C_matrix[l][i][j],[fid_values[j],fid_values[i]],sq_tab_A,'0.8',couleur[l],2.48,0.8,x[j],"",minx[j],maxx[j],minx[i],maxx[i],tri_len,tri_len,tri_len*i+(j+1),i,j)                             
        
            else:
                ellipsePlot_A=plt_ell2(C_matrix[l][j][j],C_matrix[l][i][i],C_matrix[l][i][j],[fid_values[j],fid_values[i]],sq_tab_A,'0.8',couleur[l],2.48,0.8,x[j],x[i],minx[j],maxx[j],minx[i],maxx[i],tri_len,tri_len,tri_len*i+(j+1),i,j)                           
                
            l=l+1
        l=0
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
    j=0
```

I expect to understand why I don't get 64 elements for the multi-dimensional array `F_matrix` with dimensions (1,8,8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look closely, you will see that `F_matrix[0]` consists of 8 sub arrays (1-d arrays). Hence you get `len(F_matrix[0])` as 8. Furthermore, each of these 8 subarrays contains 8 elements so you have total 8x8 = 64 elements.

Now if you do

```
len(F_matrix[0][0])
```

you will see that it will also result in 8. Since you have 8 subarrays, `F_matrix[0]` will have indices running from 0 to 7. Specifically, each of 
which will have a length fo 8 as

```
print (len(F_matrix[0][0])) # 8
print (len(F_matrix[0][1])) # 8
print (len(F_matrix[0][2])) # 8
.
.
.
print (len(F_matrix[0][7])) # 8
```

**EDIT**

To get the total number of elements in your general multidimensional array, you first need to flatten all the dimensions to 1-d and then compute the length. So for your example, to get the length (64) you can do

```
print (len(F_matrix.flatten()))
```

`len(F_matrix[0])` represents the length (size) of the first dimension. Since you have a 3d array `(1,8,8)`, length of `F_matrix[0]` means how many further elements (can be array or list etc.) contains. These elements can in themselves be multidimensional.

Comment: what does `len(F_matrix[0])` represent ? the number of 1D arrays `F_matrix[0][i]` with `i=0:7` ? I don't understand its representation, thanks

Comment: How to get the total number of elements for `F_matrix`, i.e what is the function to get 64 elements ?

Comment: @youpilat13: To get 64 (all elements), you can do `print (len(F_matrix.flatten()))`

Comment: So `F_matrix[0]` represents the dimension of second index, i.e 8. It will give the dimension of the second index, won't it ?

Comment: `F_matrix[0]` represent the dimension (size) of the first dimension which is 1 in your case. Think of it as a single door (`[0]`) which when you open has 8 doors. And then each of these 8 doors have further 8 doors

Comment: yes this is what I would like to say, `F_matrix[i]`represents the number of (mutli or not) arrays contained into `F_matrix[i]`, this is equal to the second dimension of multi-dimensional array `F_matrix`